# Data stopped working all of a sudden

Tags: mobile-data

The H/LTE symbol beside the signal bar disappeared all of a sudden, and I no longer can connect to the internet/etc.

I still have cell signal/service (can send and receive text messages and phone calls, etc).

My new monthly plan started last week, so I haven't "used" all my data.

Not sure what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Many possible reasons as to why it's not working, but here are some things to try:

1. turn off your phone, take out the Sim card, put it back in, and turn your phone back on
2. Make sure your phone data is on. Go to settings>data usage>mobile data, make sure all options are on.
3. Check your APN settings, and make sure they are all correct. To do that, Open your phone settings, and in the search bar enter: 'access point names' check to see if the apn settings are correct. To find what the settings are supposed to be, go to Google.com and search for 'apn settings for [your carries name]' you can then add the settings by pressing on the plus symbol and manually adding them in.

   Let me know if it works.